# My variable may not have been Initialized

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I think my while loop is not even occurring and I am not quite sure why.  It is probably an something obvious however I cannot seem to find the solution.  What this code is attempting to do is use the variable "firstLetter" and add to the String "passcode" and continue to add the different characters that are specified within the while loop. however it is saying that my variable may have not been initialized which makes me think that the whole loop is messed up and is not being seen.  Im pretty new to coding so any help would be appreciated

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password 
{     
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {

    System.out.println("This program will take a phrase by you and" 
                        + "\ncreate a strong and safe password that " 
                        + "\nwill be similar.  Please enter a phrase.");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    String message = keyboard.nextLine();
    String firstLetter;
    int index = 0,
        number = 0, //a counting mechanism
        spot = 2, // how many characters in each word you put down
        pass = 1; //counting up the number of char in the password
    if (message.charAt(0) == ' '){
        System.out.println("Make sure the first character in your "
                           + "phrase is not a space");
        System.exit(1);
    }//if
    System.out.print("\nYour Password is:  ");


    char white = message.charAt(index);
    firstLetter = Character.toString(white);

    System.out.println(firstLetter); 

    index = 1;
    String passcode;
    while(index < message.length()) {
        white = message.charAt(index);
        if ((white != ' ') && (number != spot)) {
            pass = pass + 1;
            index = index + 1;
            number = number + 1;
            passcode = firstLetter + white;

        }//if
        else if (white != ' ') {
                index = index + 1;
        }//else if
        else { spot = spot + 1;
               number = 0;
               index = index + 1;
        }//else
        }//while
    System.out.print(passcode);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a variable passcode like:

```
String passcode;
```

The only way to initialize it when you go in while loop (meaning while condition satisfies), you go into if `if ((white != ' ') && (number != spot)) {` What if it doesn't satisfies condition? That means you dont have any values for pass code and then you try to access it like:

```
System.out.print(passcode);
```

Hence compiler complains about the same. So you need to do something addition to String declaration like:

```
String passcode = "";//define it as well with default value and you might need to check defining values within if/else where its not already present
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had a brief look at the code, I feel this would not compile and complain about passcode variable not being initialized. What if the condition

index < message.length() is not true first time and while loop is never entered!!

I guess that explains why compiler is giving error.

You can initialize passcode to any value, null or empty string may be depending on your use case which I am not sure of.

Hope this helps.